# Flutter x and y coordinate system

Tags: flutter

I created an x and y coordinate system and used GridView and CustomPainter. However, the designs of the GridView and CustomPainter shift on different screens, and the image I desire does not appear as intended. How can I make it fit perfectly for every screen? My screen code is provided below.

```
Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, right: 10),
                    child: GridView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: gridCount,
                        childAspectRatio: 1,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                      ),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final int x = index % gridCount;
                        final int y = gridCount - 1 - (index ~/ gridCount);
                        final Point<int> point = Point(x, y);
                        final int distance = guesses[point] ?? -1;
                        final bool isHiddenPoint = point == hiddenPoint;
                        final bool isGuessedPoint =
                            guesses.keys.contains(point);
                        Color backgroundColor;
                        if (isHiddenPoint && distance == 0) {
                          backgroundColor = Colors.green;
                        } else if (isGuessedPoint) {
                          backgroundColor = Colors.blue;
                        } else {
                          backgroundColor = Colors.transparent;
                        }
                        return GridTile(
                          child: Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: backgroundColor,
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              distance >= 0 ? distance.toString() : '',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      itemCount: gridCount * gridCount,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: 0,
                  left: 30,
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: 145,
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: AxisPainter2(gridCount),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

The custom painter code is provided here:

```
class AxisPainter2 extends CustomPainter {
  final int gridCount;

  AxisPainter2(this.gridCount);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 0.2;
    final textStyle = TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 14,
    );
    final textSpan = TextSpan(
      text: '',
      style: textStyle,
    );
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: textSpan,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );

    canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, size.height - 15),
        Offset(size.width, size.height - 15), paint);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      final dx = size.width / gridCount * i;
      if (i != 0) {
        canvas.drawCircle(Offset(dx, size.height - 15), 3, paint);
      }
      textPainter.text = TextSpan(text: i == 0 ? '' : '$i', style: textStyle);
      textPainter.layout();
      textPainter.paint(
          canvas, Offset(dx - textPainter.width / 2, size.height - 10));

      if (i != 0) {
        canvas.drawLine(Offset(dx, size.height - 15), Offset(dx, 10), paint);
      }
    }

    const yOffset = 16.0;
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, 10), Offset(0, size.height), paint);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
      final dy = size.height / 10 * (gridCount - i) - yOffset;
      if (i != gridCount) {
        canvas.drawCircle(Offset(0, dy), 3, paint);
      }
      textPainter.text =
          TextSpan(text: i == gridCount ? '' : '$i', style: textStyle);
      textPainter.layout();
      textPainter.paint(
          canvas, Offset(-8 - textPainter.width, dy - textPainter.height / 2));

      if (i != gridCount) {
        canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, dy), Offset(size.width, dy), paint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Everything in the emulator is as I want it, but there is a shift in the design across different screens. How can I ensure responsive design for every screen?